# PagerJS/KnockoutJS Sub-page nested binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding, pagerjs

I'm having an issue using a nested object with pager.js and knockout.js.

I have a single page view-model which loads the information for a subpage in a function, and the function is called in a "withOnShow" data-bind.

The subpage itself loads fine, but I'm not able to access any of the elements of an object that I am passing to the sub page using the "with" data-bind.

I have tried loading the elements these ways:

- $data.etc
- $data.notifications.etc
- notifications.notifications.etc
- notifications.etc
- notifications().etc
- notifications().notifications.etc
- self.notifications.notifications.etc
- self.notifications().notifications.etc

I have also tried changing the type of my observable element from "ko.observable([])" to "ko.observableArray([])", as well as toggling between using and not using the "with" binding. The relevant code follows as (this is in my main page jsp in a viewmodel function in a script tag):

```
self.notifications = ko.observable({});
self.loadNotifications = function(callback, page) {
    $.getJSON("${pageContext.request.contextPath}/static/json/notificationtest.json", function(notifications) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(notifications, {}, self.notifications);
        callback(self);
        console.log(self.notifications());
    });
}
```

And the relevant HTML follows as (this is in my main-page jsp):

```
<div data-bind="page: {id: 'profile', role: 'start'}">
   <div data-bind="page: {id: 'notifications', sourceOnShow: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/action/secured/user/profile/notifications',
    title: 'Notifications', with: self.notifications, withOnShow: loadNotifications}">
</div>
```

An example of what I'm trying to do (this code is in my sub-page jsp):

```
<div data-bind="if: $data.manager">
<!-- then one kind of view with a lot of stuff going on happens -->
<div data-bind="ifnot: $data.manager">
<!-- otherwise this view pops up -->
```

This is just one way I'm trying to access data. I also have some other booleans I access, as well as some arrays which are used to populate forms. The JSON follows as:

```
{   
"notifications": {
    "sameList": false,
    "displayMessage1": true,
    "displayMessage2": false,
    "displayMessage3": true,
    "dm1Global": false,
    "dm2Global": true,
    "dm3Global": true,
    "manager": true,
    "contacts": [
        {"name": "NAME1"}, {"name": "NAME2"}, {"name": "NAME3"}
    ],
    "contacts1": [
        {"name": "NAME4"}
    ],
    "contacts2": [
     ""   
    ],
    "contacts3": [
     {"name": "NAME5"}, {"name": "NAME6"}   
    ]
    }
}
```

Any insight? Thanks! (apologies if I asked the question poorly, let me know if I need to provide more!)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/15/  let's work here if you can replicate your issue .

Comment: @Matt.kaaj Thanks! So I tried to implement something like that in my code (used a with binding of my viewModel, changed the self.notification to self.Notifications, and tried calling on the elements using Notifications().manager), but now I'm getting the error "Reference Error: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return Notifications.manager }" I think that this means that it cannot actually access the Notifications() object. ODDLY Enough, when I put a div in to check to see if it was getting the correct value of Notifications().manager, it was!

Comment: Can you attempt to update the jsfiddle link with the sample you are trying to do ?

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to think of a way to change it, but my example uses two different files, and I'm not sure how to show that in jsfiddle. My sub-page is structured similarly to the existing fiddle for what it matters, and that's where I'm getting my erratic behavior. The div requesting the text works, the div trying to evaluate the boolean does not.

Comment: try this `data-bind="if: Notifications() && Notifications().manager() "`

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work, even without the parentheses at the end of manager. I'm confused as to why it works in one situation but not the other; it seems like the variable is in the scope, so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: probably the hierarchy of your `DOM` elements  is not bound to your desired view model scope properly.